# Use a library with idea

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, json-simple

I am trying to use a library in my java project, I am using intelij IDEA.
For some reason, in IDEA I don't have any errors, the code compile, but when I build an artefact and run it I have this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser
```

I have import the class in the file where I use the librarie and json-simple is in my module list.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"when I build an artefact and run it"_ Are you running it from IntelliJ, or from the command line? If the latter, can you please share the command you're using?

Comment: Check the jar content - does it actually have the `org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser` class file?

Comment: @Andrey It does contain the jar file at the root (in project.jar I have json-simple-1.1.1.jar)

Comment: @dnault I am running it from command line: java -jar project.jar.

Comment: Ok I just found the solution, in my 3rd screen, the librairie is imported to the project, in the project I do not have the `org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser` class file. the librarie need to be extracted (right click on Available content > extract). Thx for the help